# Memory leaks in R when using a ~ operator

Tags: r

I am following the examples from http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html. In one of the examples a function of the following form is proposed (after loading the package *pryr*):

```
f2 <- function() {
  x <- 1:1e6
  z ~ x
}
mem_change(y <- f2())
object_size(y)
```

in this case, I can see that memory is not released because the value of *mem_change* includes the memory space of vector *x*.

I tried the following function where I delete the vector *x* explicitly and here I can see that mem_change doesn't include the memory for *x*:

```
f3 <- function() {
  x <- 1:1e6
  z ~ x
  rm(x)
}
mem_change(y <- f3())
object_size(y)
```

what I don't know is what the operator *~* is actually doing in the first function and regarding the second function, is that the proper way to release memory inside a function?

Thanks

Comment: That page also states *"the two main causes of memory leaks are formulas and closures because they both capture the enclosing environment"*. In your second example, the environment has had `x` removed, so the apparent size should change. As for "proper way" ... not sure exactly. Returning a formula is not a thing I do frequently (okay ... *at all*), and I don't know of many packages that do return formulas. Good question.

Comment: thanks for your comment, this what I don't understand, what is the "environment" that I guess "~" is creating?

Comment: The environment contains all the local variables created while evaluating the function.  It has a link to the environment where the function was created, which has a link to its parent, etc.  The formula doesn't create it, it just contains a link to the local environment, so every variable there is preserved as long as the formula exists.